# Missing personal api in geth JS consoole

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, geth-debugging, api

so I installed geth. and launched the genesis terminal after initializing my genesis block. I needed to run the personal.newAccount() command, but the personal api is missing. My colleague had the same issue, but he said he just restarted the console, which didn't work for me. I tried starting over from scratch, but it's still the same thing. Please how do I add it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The personal RPC namespace is now deprecated. In order to interact with personal APIs, you need to specifically allow it via the --rpc.enabledeprecatedpersonal command-line flag.  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.11.0

Comment: thank you for your answer. I found out about it being deprecated and that clef is the new account manager. I'm alreayd using clef. Thanks